# Left join results in cross join in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two tables in pyspark using a SQLContext:

```
create table joined_table stored 
as orc
as
SELECT  A.*,
        B.*
FROM TABLEA AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON 1=1
where lower(A.varA) LIKE concat('%',lower(B.varB),'%')
AND (B.varC = 0 OR (lower(A.varA) = lower(B.varB)));
```

But I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: u'Detected cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans

parquet\nJoin condition is missing or trivial.\nUse the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
```

Edit:

I solved the problem using the following in Spark:

```
conf.set('spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled', 'true')
```

This enables the cross join in Pyspark!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the on clause condition with your left join.. A Left join without join condition will always results in cross join. A cross join will repeat each row of your left hand table  for each row the table on your right side.  Can you edit your query and include the 'ON' clause with your join key column.

Comment: I tried adding a `on 1=1` condition to it but it gives me the same error. I also cannot change the `where` condition to an `ON` condition.

Comment: @Siddharth.. provide your sample data with your expected output.

Comment: I’ve edited my question to include the answer. Apart from adding the ON condition, I had to set the spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled to true. This did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Your question says that you do not want a cross join product